# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ''1'' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update columns that are numbered, however I am getting a warning that these columns do not exist, even though I do have a column 1 in `TRIPLECROWNpicks`

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ''1'' in 'field list'

```
$sql = "UPDATE TRIPLECROWNpicks SET `:pick` = :replace WHERE `user_id` = :user_id";
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':user_id', $_POST['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':replace', $replace, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':pick', $_POST['pick'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot parametrize table or column names. Only values.

So if you want to use different columns then use completly seperate queries.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot parametrize column names.

Either you concatenate update string (not preferable  -there is possibility for SQL injection) or create a map of prepared statements, and use pick property as selector for them.

Answer (score 0):

You bind value here and claim it to be integer.

```
$stmt->bindValue(':pick', $_POST['pick'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Then you use it here as column name

```
SET `:pick` = :replace
```

There are at least two things wrong here:

1. Integer for column name is a bad idea.
2. And you should not use parameters as columns names.